# TIFF View, Annotate, and Redact

Tags: .net, wpf

Need a .NET WPF tool (control) to view, annotate, and redact TIFF images.

It must support non reversible redaction.
Cannot peek under the redaction and see the content.
It needs to erase the content under the redaction.
This is for a legal application and the content must be gone.

Also need simple annotation and shrink (create a white border).

So far have found Lead Tools but have not tried it out.

Answer (score -1):

The cheapest way to do this is to use Imaging for Windows. You'll need to buy a licence for each client PC but this will view, annotate and (if you burn the annotations or delete areas) redact.

http://www.imaging-for-windows.com

I notice I've been marked down (not sure why) but I should add this isn't just an application. Imaging for Windows provides a set of APIs you can call from your code to do the annotation / display / redaction etc.